# Rails app going live with Passenger with redirect_to error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have deployed my rails app successfully with passenger. However my redirect_to is acting differently in the production environment than the development environment.

I have this code:

```
redirect_to( :page => :signup, :subdomain => false)
```

On the development app it works great so:

http://demo.charterbox.com.au redirects to `http://charterbox.com.au/?page=signup` perfect!

On the production app which I just uploaded it does this:

http://demo.charterbox.com.au redirects to `http://com.au/?page=signup`

Instead of just taking the subdomain away, it took the whole domain. Doesn't matter if I use a sub-domain or not, it will still just redirect to `http://.com.au`

Here is the full code in the ApplicationsController:

```
before_filter :check_domain

def check_domain

  if request.subdomain.blank? == false
     @account = Account.where("site_address = ?", request.subdomain).limit(1)      
     if @account.empty? 
       redirect_to( :page => :signup, :subdomain => false)
     end
  end

end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the TLD length.

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length sets the TLD (top-level domain) length for the application. Defaults to 1.
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-dispatch

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to make much of a difference. It says it defaults to 1 anyway which the top-level domain is 1. Isn't it?

Comment: demo.charterbox.com.au -- TLD length is 2... "com.au", isn't it?

Comment: The demo subdomain is just a wildcard naming convention. Sometimes it wont have a sub-domain and the app will run just as charterbox.com.au